# Microsoft Robotics Development Studio simulation project deployment

Tags: deployment, simulation, robotics

I am currently working on a project in Microsoft Robotics Development Studio, and I am having a little trouble deploying the solution for general use.

My problem is this.  I am making a simulation, so I need to deploy the simulation engine along with my project.  This is dependent on the Ageia PhysX engine, DirectX, and the Microsoft XNA framework.  I understand this, and I understand that the deployment tool for MRDS (dssdeploy) isn't set up to deploy simulations by default.  So, if anyone has worked with MRDS before, and has deployed a simulation, I could use some help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, dssdeploy does not work with simulation projects.  It won't package up all the required simulation libraries.  I believe the reason for this is due to license and/or install issues for PhysX, DirectX, and XNA.  I think you can still zip up your own service with dssdeploy, but you will have to have your target user install RDS first, then un-deploy your service.

FYI, because of this and many other headaches using dssdeploy, I have stopped using it to distribute my code.  I simply zip up my service, then tell the end user to run dssprojectmigration on the code after they un-zip it.